# jquery: auto-create url from title

Tags: jquery

i'm looking for jQuery code which will suggest me a URL for new CMS article, based on the Title of article.

Example:

> **I wrote title:** The sky is blue
>
> **jQuery autogenerated URL:**
>   /the-sky-is-blue/

Answer (score 2):

```
function slugify(str){
    return str.replace(/\s+/g,'-').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/g,'').toLowerCase();
}

var mySlug = slugify("testing the slugify function"); // testing-the-slugify-function
```

Comment: +1 - taking care of the invalid characters is very important here.

Answer (score 0):

One way without jquery:

```
var title = text.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
```